# What does AJAX timeout actually measure?

Tags: jquery, ajax, networking, xmlhttprequest, timeout

I have several jQuery and AngularJS AJAX calls in my code with timeout values such as this (jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    timeout : 5000,
    data: data
});
```

Or this (Angular):

```
$http.post(url, data, {timeout:5000}).then(function(response){});
```

My question is what does the timeout parameter actually measure? I have varied the timeout and ran various tests. I also monitored the network requests in my browser but that only made me more confused. I noticed the measurements noted in the timeline are not very good predictors of whether or not the request will timeline. For example, I can have a request on the order of milliseconds that triggers a timeout with my timeout parameter set to 5 seconds. Obviously there is at least one other factor at play here and I am not a networking expert to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override
>   any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts
>   at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in
>   progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible
>   for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and
>   below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the
>   request times out; accessing any object members may throw an
>   exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be
>   cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after
>   the timeout period.

This is what the jquery ajax says.

that said, Time is a factor that is dependent on almost every stack from browser to network. Its hard to give a specific answer unless you have clear defined experiment.